# Postfix forwarding to Gmail and local UNIX user

Tags: postfix, mail-forwarding

I would like to forward all email coming to everything in `@foo.com` to `bar@gmail.com` and also to the UNIX user `baz`.

I tried adding both `baz` and `bar@gmail.com` to the `virtual` file (see config below), but it only seems to forward mails to `bar@gmail.com` and not add it to `/var/mail/baz`. No errors regarding delivering to `baz` show up in the log either (nor does it even mention `baz` in the `/var/log/mail.log`; `bar@gmail.com` *does* show up in the log though with a `status=sent`, after which `qmgr` says "removed"; no further information about the test email shows up).

Is there something that I am missing? [`man 5 virtual`](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html) says `@domain address, address, ...` is accepted as a pattern, so I *think* this should just work, right?

`/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mailme
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, mailme.foo.com, mailme, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
# Use only ipv4; for some reason ipv6 (used when set to "all") causes "network unreachable" messages in /var/log/mail.log
inet_protocols = ipv4

# Forwarding
virtual_alias_domains = foo.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

`/etc/postfix/virtual`:

```
@foo.com        baz, bar@gmail.com
```

Comment: What happens if you make an entry in `aliases`? I'm not clear why that won't work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tested by adding `baz: /var/mail/baz` to `/etc/aliases` (and running `newaliases` and restarting postfix) but it still won't work.

Comment: Did you run postmap on /etc/postfix/virtual ?

Answer (score 0):

`@foo.com` within your `/etc/postfix/virtual` is a wildcard. ( extract from the comment within `/etc/postfix/virtual` ).

This means that everything destinated to `user@foo.com` will be accepted if `user` is a local account or not.

Within your `virtual` file, `baz` isn't a correct address,
it is a user account.
A correct address would be `baz@mydomain`.
And of course, `mydomain` couldn't be `foo.com` nor anything within a subdomain, unless you want to play with infinite rewriting loops.